# Twilio "Access Token has expired or expiration date is invalid"

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I get this warning in my Twilio programmable video console periodically.  It doesn't seem to be affecting my video sessions, but because, well, I'm a bit obsessive, I'd like to know how to make this warning go away.

Is there a prescribed method of refreshing tokens while a room is in progress?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

While an access token expiring does not cause Video sessions to finish, you can keep your tokens alive if you use the `AccessManager` library that Twilio also distributes. The `AccessManager` will emit an event or call a delegate method when the token is close to expiry and you can use that to refresh the token.

You can read about [how to use the `AccessManager`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/access-token-lifecycle) here. That article is part of the Chat documentation, but Chat and Video both use tokens the same way and support the `AccessManager` the same way too.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like what I need.  So, how do I test my code?  Can i request a short expiration time when I create a token?  waiting 24 hours to see if it worked is a little challenging...

Comment: You can set a different expiration time by passing a `ttl` argument of the seconds until expiration when you initialize your AccessToken. I'm not sure which language you're using, but if you let me know I can write an example.

Comment: I found that.  The problem is the programmable video client doesn't have an AccessManager or a way to refresh tokens.  If I have a room established, and my tokens expire, what do I do?

Comment: Sorry, the video client doesn't have an access manager, that distributed separately as [`twilio-common`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-common). Check out [this guide on initializing a Video Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/video/identity#client-initialize-the-sdk-with-an-access-token) that might help too.

Comment: OK, I found the AccessManager in twilio-common.  However, I don't see any way to use AM to set up video connections.  The link you gave points to something called a "conversations client", which doesn't show up in either twilio-video or twilio-common.  I tried installed 'twilio-conversations", but it appears to only install twilio-video.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I've gone down the wrong rabbit hole here. The `AccessManager` was used until mid 2016 then removed (and Conversations were deprecated). The `AccessManager` was useful when there was a long lived Video client, now you just call `connect` with a fresh token each time you want to join a room. You might just have to deal with the warnings (or stop logging warnings in production). The only reason this is a problem is if you are trying to `connect` to a room with an out of date token.

Comment: The problem is I don't want to leave the room, I just want to refresh the tokens and ensure that everyone is still connected to the room.  What's the best practice for 24x7 video rooms?

Comment: I submitted a ticket for this one.  I'll post my solution once I figure out how to do this.

Comment: A token expiry won't end a video session. The best practice is to generate a token for a user as soon as they want to join the room and authorize their connection with that token. They can then stay connected as long as they want.